# in a loop, only add to a dictionary or list or tuple if doesn't contains the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looping in python and want to add a key to a dictionary only if it isn't already in the collection.

How can I do this?

```
mydic = {}

for x in range(100):
    ??
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a dict, it's easy and fast:

```
for x in range(100):
  if x not in mydic:
    mydic[x] = x  # or whatever value you want
```

that is, just check with `not in` instead of `in`.

This is great for a dict.  For a list, it's going to be extremely slow (quadratic); for speed, you need to add an auxiliary set (hopefully all items in the list are hashable) before the loop, and check and update it in the loop.  I.e.:

```
auxset = set(mylist)
for x in range(100):
  if x not in auxset:
    auxset.add(x)
    mylist.append(x)  # or whatever
```

For a tuple, it's impossible to add anything to it, or in any other way modify it, of course: tuples are immutable!  Surely you know that?!  So, why ask?

Comment: how do I get the # of items in the dic?

Comment: @Blankman, `len(mydic)`, of course.  Have you even **looked** at the Python tutorial?  You really should, you know!

Comment: i tried that and got an error...hmmm. (looking at the doc page actually, which makes it worse? )

Comment: You might use `for x in range(len(mydic)):` if I'm correctly inferring what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Blankman, if `len(mydic)` gives an error, then `mydic` is definitely not a dictionary (nor a list nor any other normal container).

Comment: @magcius, I consider `setdefault` a well-intentioned but failed experiment (and I had enough to do with its inception, even though I played a very minor role in it, that this can be taken as repentance on my part).  `collections.defaultdict` does essentially what the `setdefault` method of dict was intended to do, _so_ much better.

Comment: +1 for the use of `auxset` instead of directly using the `mylist`.